# How to send 'list' json request when using Guzzle?

Tags: php, json, guzzle

I am using Guzzle to write php sdk for a server, I want to use Guzzle to send http json body like this:

```
["test_1","test_2"]
```

But when I write this code, I got the wrong json:

```
$body = array(
    'test_1',
    'test_2',
);
$guzzleRequest = guzzleClient->createRequest(
        $httpMethod,
        $url,
        $headers,
        $body,
        $guzzleRequestOptions
);
$guzzleResponse = $this->guzzleClient->send($guzzleRequest);
```

I am sending this wrong json to the server.

```
{"0":"test_1","1":"test_2"}
```

So, my question is HOW CAN I SEND JSON BODY LIKE A LIST USING Guzzle?

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
$guzzleRequest = guzzleClient->createRequest(
    $httpMethod,
    $url,
    $headers,
    json_encode($body),
    $guzzleRequestOptions
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me to send json by Guzzle

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
// url destination 
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';
// headers , if the api dosen't require access token you can remove Authorization from header
$headers = [
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => "bearer ".$access_token
];
// body
$body = [
    '1' => 'test1',
    '2' => 'test2'
];
// init Guzzle
$client = new client();
// init Guzzle
$response = $client->post($url , [
    'headers' => $headers, 
    'json' => $body,
]);

$status_code = $response->getStatusCode(); // 200
$status_message = $response->getReasonPhrase(); // ok
```